# Is there a way in nginx to redirect directly from / to /page with using sites-available?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am currently trying to figure out how to set up a base redirect for a server.  The issue is when typing in the URL: www.example.com  It gives back Not available:  /

That being said, the actual homepage for this server is www.example.com/home
Which needs to be what comes up right away when you type www.example.com

I have currently tried making a proper redirect by setting up a new sites-available (and sites-enabled link) to hopefully work as a redirect for www.example.com/, to automatically redirect to the wanted homepage, but have not found a simple way to do this yet.

In the end, to reiterate, I need it to give us the page for www.example.com/home, when you simply type www.example.com  Potentially using sites-available as a redirect to do so, cannot use index.html

Comment: The redirect needs to be in the same `server` block that handles requests for `www.example.com`. Use `nginx -T` to view the entire Nginx configuration.

Comment: Would that just be a rewrite then?  Basically rewriting whatever the user inputted and giving the wanted location?

Comment: There's more than one solution, but once you identify the correct file and `server` block to edit, adding this should work: `location = / { return 301 /home; }`